If someone moves with a velocity $v$, relative to a conductor carrying current $I$, will the current change with respect to the observer?
If someone moves with a velocity $v$, relative to a conductor carrying current $I$, will the current change with respect to the observer?
I feel that the drift velocity of current is independent of the motion of the observer. and should remain same. Could someone please confirm and give a reason?

Hint: In special relativity $J^\mu = (\rho \cdot c, \vec{j})$ is a 4-vector that transforms between reference frames

You could also look at how the $B$-field around a wire transforms, see Jackson: https://archive.org/details/ClassicalElectrodynamics2nd/page/n579/mode/2up
which is the same but in a different style as: http://www.fisica.ugto.mx/~ggutj/CV/Classical_Electrodynamics_Jackson_1a_Edicion.pdf#395

@Sancol. im a high school student, could you please give an easy explanation?

@JosBergervoet  im a high school student, could you please give an easy explanation?

I'm not sure, it is after all a relativistic effect, and Einstein said that things should be made: "as simple as possible, but not simpler!" You could look at the movingcharges and then you see a length contraction which makes them more dense. But there is also the time dilation and then there is the question whether charge itself should perhaps change in magnitude... To understand it all you have to study it!
